# What is the real use of kafka based multi ordering service

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am new in fabric technologies. I read some articles about the Kafka based ordering services and its advantage. Some of articles say that Kafka based multi ordering services is suitable for fault tolerance. Now i just apply 3 Kafka based ordering services(orderer0,orderer1,orderer2). Then i stopped 2 orderer using the following command

```
docker stop orderer1.example.com
docker stop orderer2.example.com
```

Now the Rest api working correctly. Then i stopped orderer0 using

```
docker stop orderer0.example.com
```

Now my Rest api is not working.It has facing network connection problem.Then I started orderer1,orderer2 using the following command

```
docker start orderer1.example.com
docker start orderer2.example.com
```

But my Rest api is not working...........It has facing the same network connection problem.

And finally I started orderer0 using

```
docker start orderer0.example.com
```

Now the network is working fine.

My questions is

1. What is actual use of Kafka based ordering services..??
2. How we can implement Kafka based ordering service for prevent the orderer downing problem...??

Fabric:1.1.0
Composer:0.19.16
Node:8.11.3
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Is the above scenario assuming a multi replica Kafka topic and producing clients configured to not acknowledge all replicas have received a write? E.g two replicas of three down, generally means the kafka topic is unhealthy

Comment: Yes, i use multiple kafka based orderer services. Can you help me in my question...???

Comment: I don't know hyperledger, so I can't really answer your specific question, but Kafka make no message-ordering guarantees outside of a single partition of a topic (not across partitions, and not across topics, and not across brokers)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you when I wanted to set up several orderer. To solve this problem I have 2 solutions:

1. I changed the SDK, currently your SDK tries to contact the orderer0 if it fails it returns an error, it is necessary to change this so that the request loop on a list of orderer and returns an error if no is valid.
2. easier: set up a load-balancer upstream of the orderers.

To answer your question. The advantage of setting up Kafka based ordering services is that the data of the proposed blocks are spread over several servers. There is a fault tolerance because if an orderer crashes and reconnects to the kafka cluster it will be able to resynchronize. The performances are better (it's theoretical I did not test on this point)

Comment: Hey...Thanks for answering.. I don't understand that change made in SDK . Please clear me

Answer (score 0):

As per [Kafka Ordering Services](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/kafka.html)

> Each channel maps to a separate single-partition topic in Kafka

This means that all messages in the topic are totally-ordered in the order in which they were sent.

and

> At a minimum, [the number of brokers] should be set to 4. (As we will explain in Step 4 below, this is the minimum number of nodes necessary in order to exhibit crash fault tolerance, i.e. with 4 brokers, you can have 1 broker go down, all channels will continue to be writeable and readable, and new channels can be created.)

The above assumes a Kafka replication factor of 3 and the producing client to set `min.insync.replicas` ideally to 2 to make sure that all writes are replicated to at least two servers.

Based on your network issues, this sounds to me like you did not actually configure all three brokers correctly (would need to see your entire Docker setup and what the Dockerfile is actually doing). But, assuming you did configure all three brokers for this "REST API", and there is a single-partition Kafka topic with 3 replicas (the default replication is 1, and topics are auto-created with this). So, I suggest you clean it all, then start three brokers, then manually create the topic with 1 partition, 3 replicas, then start Hyperledger.

If the REST API is the actual problem, not the Kafka connection, then you would need a load-balancer, I guess